# Constructing a basis that includes $1-t^3$ and $1+t^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question goes like: Construct a basis that includes $1-t^3$ and $1+t^3$ for the vector space of polynomials in variable $t$, where the *degree* of polynomial is $\le3$.

So we have to construct a basis which already includes  $1-t^3$ and $1+t^3$, that means we have to find just *one* more value. I tried some rough calculations that didn't make much sense and got another vector as $t^3$. How should I go upon solving this problem?

Comment: The space you mention has dimension 4... You need two more elements.

Comment: Hint , once you figure out that you actually need two more elements rather than one : what is the standard basis for your space? It's $\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}$. Using the above two vectors, which of these polynomials can you get? Those that you cannot get, you can add to your set, right? (Note : Consider converting an attempt into an answer once you are sure that it's correct, it makes a lot of sense to self-answer).

Comment: Just to confirm, $1-t^3$ and $1-t^3$ are of the form $at^3+b$, so the polynomials left are of the form, $at^2+b$, $at+b$, so will these form the basis? Like all the polynomials of the form $at^2+b$ and $at+b$,will form basis for our case? @TeresaLisbon

Comment: @VaiebhavPatil Yes, so for example, $t$ and $t^2$ would work.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I understood it. @TeresaLisbon

Comment: The moral of the story should be that it isn’t a problem: pick any two polynomials randomly enough and that’ll do it.